# jQuery dynamic page loading - Other javascript is broken and how should i import page specific js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, loading

Okay, so this one is gonna be a doozy!

**NOTE: This will be for a windows desktop application running sqlite and mongoose, so loading times are not as important (to me, for now) and there will be no connection to a non-local server.**

I have searched all over and couldn't find anything that is specific to my situation, most seem to load into an iframe or use that framework provided by css-tricks.com

I am using my own (sorta) framework. The libraries i am using are bootstrap 3, jquery 2.1.4, jqueryui 1.12.1, and Bootstrap-select v1.12.1

index.php will have all content dynamically loaded into a div#wrapper and will act as the head of all page loading. This is the skeleton of my index.php. In sidebar.html the links have the attribute 'pagetoload', jquery catches the click event and loads the data into div#wrapper

```
    <body>
      <?php require_once("res/sidebar.html"); ?>
      <div class="container-fluid" id="body-container">
        <div id="wrapper" style="border:1px black solid;">
           <!-- dynamic page content will be loaded here-->
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="res/js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="res/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="res/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="res/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
      <script src="res/js/menu-handling.js"></script>



    <script>
    //index.php js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.get("home.php", function (data) {
            $("div#wrapper").html(data);
        });


        $("a.loader").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr("pagetoload"), function (data) {
                $("div#wrapper").html(data);
            });
        });
        //dateFormat 10/dd/yy to constrain input only to october
        //get current month number and constrain to prevent additions to wrong month
        $("#date-input").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "12/dd/yy"
            , constrainInput: true
        });
        $("#date-input").focus(function () {
            $(this).datepicker("show");
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Each page that will be dynamically loaded will ideally contain minimal php and only contain the necessary html/css/js for that page. My issue is for example, after loading one page such as my dbviewer.php (which contains js and gives me the asynchronous loading warning) and reloading home.php into the container, javascript no longer works. The javascript for each page are inline  tags.

I have tried piling all the javascript for every dynamic page into index.php so that it's all loaded on startup, but the issue arises that it still won't work. What is the best method make this dynamic loading work while having each page modular. I have tried to researching this but only stuff like using the hashTag thing comes up.

**If you need more code from my files please post, i think i explained it enough for you to understand as there is nothing too wild going on outside of index.php  Just scripts inside each dynamic page that basically interacts with dom elements using jquery.**

Comment: your app is SPA, single page app, and in that case I suggest you go with loading all javascript in the 'master' `index` page,, and then for each additional page to simply do `$.ajax` requests to your php files,, and that's it!

Comment: the problem that you have is not how to rearange the app, and php files, but javascript/jQuery callback programing,, or how to do some JS/data manipulation after you pull some data on X page,, am I right?

Comment: I have tried having index.php load all js and any js such as displaying dynamic form for insert to db doesn't work if i do that but it does if the js is inline with the page.

Comment: After reloading back to 'home' from The menu, which will dynamic load home.php any js such as bootstrap drop down, datepicker, or any other js is broken

Comment: you have to separate all javascript, css assets in `master` file to host them on first pageload, and all other files to not load any `duoble` same javascript because for sure they will colide,, for all php files you have do structure them to be only data for that page user selected.. after that you have to trigger $.ajax `callback` function to do job on that page after data was loaded..

Comment: Thank you oserk, i will give that a go and respond with results tomorrow

Comment: I did what you said and just loaded all content initially and now im just hiding or showing divs essentially to navigate. Thank you!

Comment: great, I'm happy that it helped you, do you agree that I post answer and you accept it, maybe it can be of general help to developers in similar situations?

Comment: Absolutely, I'm sure someone else will find it useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving this answer because it helped you, and also can be usefull as a general rule of thumb for any developer out there that can find himself in similar situation.

So when developing the app you have to separate all javascript, css assets in master file to host them on first pageload. (maybe it's event better for performance)

All other server generated files (`php`, `node.js` etc) files you have do structure to only be data source for pages that users click or land to .. or at least try to..

after that you have to trigger

`$.ajax().callback`

function on frontend to do job on each page. Such as page effects, data manipulation and etc .. Callback is very important because that's when data was actually loaded!

cheers, k